# TMUX. Писать во все окна одновременно

Tags: linux, bash, tmux

Учусь пользоваться терминальным мультиплексором tmux. Есть задание - написать скрипт bash, который принимает в качестве аргумента количество pane (=n) и при запуске создает n штук pane, деля одно окно на n. И ввод данных должен происходить одновременно во все окна. Вопрос: как писать во все окна одновременно? И как можно красиво поделить одно окно на несколько, я научился пользователя самыми примитивными командами - вроде ctl + b (" % -> <- ^ v (стрелки))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так:

```
Ctrl-B :

setw synchronize-panes on
```

подробнее тут
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325449/how-to-send-a-command-to-all-panes-in-tmux